# if user does not select then form send email but in email it should not have this field

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, email

I have this form to email: http://test4.bycustomdesign.com/order-form.shtml

The form is working great. Noticed I have a bunch of menu list select box to select a different size, etc. The default initial select is always "Select"

I wish to: if a user does not select anything, then it is ok to send form. However, in the email I get, if the user did not select anything, then it would not be in the email. Or if it left to default "Select" then it should not be in the email. Because not all fields are selected and in the email I will get a very long list of all fields "Select" I wish to shorten it by only sending whatever the user select, NOT all "Select"

Please help! Thank you. Michelle Ha. Here is my code:

```
// if the Email_Confirmation field is empty
if(isset($_POST['Email_Confirmation']) && $_POST['Email_Confirmation'] == ''){

// put your email address here
$youremail = 'bomandty@gmail.com, ryanjiles@betadiamond.com';

// prepare a "pretty" version of the message
$body .= "Thank you for your request. We will get back with you soon.";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "\n";
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
    if($Value != ''){
            $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
    }
}

$CCUser = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

// Use the submitters email if they supplied one
// (and it isn't trying to hack your form).
// Otherwise send from your email address.
if( $_POST['EmailAddress'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['EmailAddress']) ) {
    $headers = "From: $_POST[EmailAddress]";
} else {
    $headers = "From: $youremail";
}

// finally, send the message
mail($youremail, 'Request from BetaDiamonds.com', $body, $headers, $CCUser );
}
// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to solve this on the client like so: - use a blank value on the first item

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select an item</option>
    .... other options...
</select>
```

Comment: +1 I would also go with this approach, as it's the most flexible one. Think, you have a select box one day, that can contain `select` as a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check that the value of the field is not "Select".

```
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
if($Value != '' && $Value != 'Select' ){
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you can just add "Select" to the values that it skips. You could also set the Select option value to "", but at this point it would be easier to change the code to the following.

```
// put your email address here
$youremail = 'bomandty@gmail.com, ryanjiles@betadiamond.com';

// prepare a "pretty" version of the message
$body .= "Thank you for your request. We will get back with you soon.";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "\n";
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
    if($Value != '' && $Value != "Select"){
        $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
    }
}

$CCUser = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

// Use the submitters email if they supplied one
// (and it isn't trying to hack your form).
// Otherwise send from your email address.
if( $_POST['EmailAddress'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['EmailAddress']) ) {
  $headers = "From: $_POST[EmailAddress]";
} else {
  $headers = "From: $youremail";
}

// finally, send the message
mail($youremail, 'Request from BetaDiamonds.com', $body, $headers, $CCUser );
```